# Передача параметров странице Backbone.js

Tags: jquery, javascript, backbone.js

Привет! Подскажите, как мне открывать страницу с помощью backbone и передать ей параметр?
И как соответственно его получить?
Когда делал без бэкбона, на jQueryMobile, делал так: <a href="#page?id=13">With param</a>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решено:

```
routes: {
    "help/:page":         "help",
    "download/*path":     "download",
    "folder/:name":       "openFolder",
    "folder/:name-:mode": "openFolder"
}
```

А в функции-обработчике ловите параметры